# How to convert any text/font to its bezier path representation?

Tags: text, fonts, geometry, bezier

I have a bezier path library to draw complex bezier paths without problem. Now, I need to know how to read a text or font and extract its path information to draw it as a path instead of as text.

I came across a C application, [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/). It does exactly what I need, picks any font and extract its path information. But what I need to know is how it does it to add that feature to my drawing library.

Comment: You could read the source code to find out. http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/files/fontforge-source/

Answer (score 3):

You can use windows GDI function GetGlyphOutline.

Alternatively use BeginPath, TextOut, EndPath and GetPath. You will obtain a list of straight segments and Beziers. See [this article](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Control/GetPath-BeginPath-EndPath-draw-ourline-text.htm) for inspiration (a bit dated, but relevant).

Comment: I actually used that article as a reference for doing something similar to what the question writer wants to do... I had to convert TrueType curve commands and convert them into a device specific vector drawing language. This will definitely work.